# newline character in ruby is not working in a jQuery accordion

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to populate an accordion div with a string. I am trying to add newline character to my string, but for some reason in my accordion the newline character is not working

```
<%str = " "%>
<% user.costs.last(3).each do |cost| %>
    <%str += cost.description + " " + cost.value.to_s + " " + "\n"%>
<%end%>
<p><%=str %> </p>
```

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014986/ruby-write-newline-character-to-file-but-do-not-interpret-as-a-true-newline) before i posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newlines don't actually make a new line in HTML (except in special cases, such as `<pre>` tags):

```
<p>this
is
a
test</p>
```

will render as:

> this
>   is
>   a
>   test

[see it on a live page](http://jsfiddle.net/2dNVY/)

If you want a new line, use a `<br/>` line break tag:

```
<%str += cost.description + " " + cost.value.to_s + " " + "<br/>"%>
```

Also, use the raw string (so `<` and `>` don't get escaped):

```
<p><%=raw str %></p>
```

Comment: this results in driving2 100.0<br/>driving2 100.0<br/>blah 340.0<br/>.as an actual text in the <p>

Comment: @Quantico That's weird... it shouldn't do that... when you view the page source of that spot what do you see?

Comment: `<p class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" id="ui-accordion-accordion-panel-0" aria-labelledby="ui-accordion-accordion-header-0" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"> driving2 100.0&lt;br/&gt;driving2 100.0&lt;br/&gt;blah 340.0&lt;br/&gt; </p>`